# T-SQL to check if a list of values returned from a query exists in another table's column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have a GUID assigned to a device where a user could sign in to multiple accounts.  Every time the app runs it registers the GUID and the UserId in a table.  The GUID will remain unique but could have multiple UserId's.

I have a second table that has subscriptions for each UserId.

I need to find all UserId's returned from a search on the GUID and then see if any of those UserId's exist in the subscriptions table.

How do I do this using T SQL in MS SQL Server 2014?

Thank you.

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do an inner join on those two tables.

```
Select 
  tableA.valueColumn
  from tableA
  inner join
  tableB
  on tableA.valueColumn = tableB.valueColumn
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you supply the GUID you want to query as a parameter...

```
SELECT u.UserID, s.Subscription
FROM Users u
INNER JOIN Subscriptions s
ON u.UserID = s.UserID
WHERE u.GUID = @guid
```

Use LEFT JOIN instead of INNER JOIN if you want to include UserIDs with no subscriptions.

Answer (score 0):

The following should do the trick (you just need the last query, but i have no idea what your table names are, so i just build some crap tables/data out first)

```
    --DROP TABLE #Devices;
    CREATE TABLE #Devices(
        DeviceGUID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER DEFAULT NEWSEQUENTIALID() PRIMARY KEY,
        DeviceName VARCHAR(20)
        )
    ;

    CREATE TABLE #Users(
        UserId INT IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY,
        Username VARCHAR(20)
        )
    ;

    CREATE TABLE #DeviceUsers(
        UserId INT,
        DeviceGUID UNIQUEIDENTIFIER
        )
    ;

    --add some devices
    INSERT INTO #Devices(DeviceName) VALUES ('Device1'), ('Device2');

    --add some users
    INSERT INTO #Users(Username) VALUES ('User1'), ('User2');

    --add some deviceusers
    INSERT INTO #DeviceUsers(UserId, DeviceGUID)
    SELECT u.UserId, d.DeviceGUID
    FROM #Users u
        CROSS JOIN #Devices d
    ;

    SELECT u.*, d.*
    FROM #DeviceUsers du
        INNER JOIN #Users u
            ON du.UserId = u.UserId
        INNER JOIN #Devices d
            ON d.DeviceGUID = du.DeviceGUID
    WHERE d.DeviceGUID = 'Some GUID Goes Here'
```

;